# Existence (and uniqueness) of root of function with positive and strictly increasing derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, roots, monotone-functions

Consider a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and assume that:

- $f(a)<0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
- $f'(a)\geq 0$ and $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing in $(a,+\infty)$.

My question is: is it guaranteed that there exists a $b>a$ such that $f(b)=0$ (in that case, $b$ would be unique, ofc)? My intuition says yes, but I cannot find such a theorem in the literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(a+1)\ge 0$ then the desired $b$ exists by the intermediate value theorem. Otherwise, $f(a+1)<0$ and $f'(a+1)\ge \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$,
so $f(a+1+k/\epsilon) \ge f(a+1)+k$ by the mean value theorem, so $f$ is eventually positive, whence it must vanish somewhere by the intermediate value theorem.

Edit: As noted by Lázaro Albuquerque in a comment, one needs to first explain why $f'(b) \ge 0$ for all $b>a$, as the hypothesis only states that $f'$ is strictly increasing on the open interval $(a,\infty)$. Indeed, if $f'(b)=-\delta<0$ for some $b>a$, then $f'(t)<-\delta$ for all $t \in (a,b)$, and this would contradict Darboux's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, but if I may ask two follow-up questions:
1) First, how do you know that $b$ is finite?
2) Second, instead of the second assumption, assume the following:
 a) for all $i>0$, $f^{(i)}(a)\geq 0$.
 b) there exists $p>1$ such that $f^{(p)}(a)\geq 0$,
where, by $f^{(i)}(\cdot)$ we denote the $i-$th derivative of $f$. 
Can we now guarantee the existence of $b$?

Comment: I guess my first question can be answered by the fact that your statement holds for any $k>0$. So, if we take $k$ such that $f(a+1)+k=0$, then $f(a+1+k/\epsilon)\geq 0$, and then by continuity $\exists b\in(a,a+1+k/\epsilon)$ such that $f(b)=0$. AM I right? ANd what about the second question?

Comment: And for the second question, I guess that the new assumptions impose that  $f'(a)\geq0$ and that $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing in $(a,+\infty)$, so again we have existence of $b$. Am I right?

Comment: In your second question, did you want a strict inequality?

Comment: yes yes, I am sorry. I meant: b) there exists $p>1$ such that $f^{(p)}(a)>0$.

Comment: Then the previous proof scheme will work

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Something should be said about $f'$ being right-continuous at $a$.

Comment: @Lázaro Albuquerque: You are right, I am editing the answer to address this.

Comment: @Gdel   If the answer is now clear, you can accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 0):

It might very well be the case that the function never crosses the $x$-axis, for example

$$f(x) = -\frac1x-k$$

satisfies your requirements with $a=1$ provided the parameter $k\leqslant 0$.

If such $b>0$ exists with $f(b) = 0$ then it will be unique because $f$ restricted to $[a,\infty)$ is injective.

Comment: It does not satisfy the requirements, because $f'(1) = -1 <0$.

Comment: Ok, I missed a−, fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: But now, $f'(x) = 1/x^2$ is decreasing on $(1,+\infty)$, so it does not satisfy the assumptions again. I think the proof by @Yuval has settled the question.